# Nested scopes in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, nested, named-scope

Is there a way that I can convert the to_be_approved by method in the following code to be a scope that uses the two other scopes?

```
scope :reports_to, lambda { |manager| 
  joins(" JOIN admin_users request_user on requests.admin_user_id = request_user.id and request_user.manager_id = #{manager.id} ") }
scope :pending, joins(:admin_request_status).where('admin_request_statuses.name = ?','Pending Approval')

def self.to_be_approved_by( manager )
  reports_to(manager).pending
end
```

I also want to get rid of the embedded sql in the reports_to scope, but that is a whole different question :)

Comment: found this for removing the embedded sql:   scope :reports_to, lambda { |manager| joins(:admin_user).where('admin_users.manager_id = ?',manager.id) }

Comment: great (mine was getting fiddly!) I'll update the answer for others since you already accepted my answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
scope :reports_to, lambda { |manager| joins(:admin_user).where('admin_users.manager_id = ?',manager.id) }  
scope :pending, joins(:admin_request_status).where('admin_request_statuses.name = ?','Pending Approval')
scope :to_be_approved_by, lambda { |manager| self.pending.reports_to(manager) }
end
```

Note to all.

Chaining scopes like this is usually ok performance-wise because the 'outer' or 'initial' scope will not be evaluated until the full scope chain is called in an example (e.g. scope_name1.scope_name2.scope_name3, etc. and only when the actual output is needed will the sql be constructed.  This is known as **"lazy loading"**, e.g. 'Be lazy, don't build results until actually needed".

This is as opposed to **"eager loading "** where you use the :include statement to get other tables and do mutiple queries "in one go" and avoid an infamous "n+1" problem which is where the program ends up executing (for example) 101 queries to get 100 records.

Lots of fun info :)

Comment: Because `scope` is a class method, I don't think it's required to call `self` in the last scope. `pending` is already accessible as a class method.